# Having Trouble in PHP debugging

Tags: php, debugging, mamp

I'm new to PHP.

Now I'm trying to fix PHP source other one already have worked. 
I succeeded to connect it with mysql using PEAR.
I'm on running it on my local, with MAMP and installed XDebug as well.

Here's the problem.

```
$select_query = " SELECT SEQ FROM TB_VISITOR WHERE VISITOR_NAME = '$visitor_name' AND VISITOR_PHONE_NO = '$visitor_phone_no' ";

$result =& $db->query($select_query);

if( PEAR::isError($result) )
{
     $result_message['result'] = false;
     $result_message['error_message'] = 'Search Fail';
}else
{
     if( $result->fetchInto($row) )
     {
          $visitor_seq = $row[0];
     }
}
```

I think that I'm blocked here, and want to know further what the problem was. What I want to see could be expressed in JQuery as 'console.log($result);

so I tried echo, echo $result > Never worked. 
Of course, console.log never worked on PHP :'(

and with XDebug I tried like
phpinfo();
I got error message ? on PHP logs
phpinfo() expects parameter 1 to be integer, object given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/smartvisiting/visitor_enrollment_proc.php on line 54

so again tried phpinfo($result);
 nothing happened.

Please let me know how I can see of 'result' in anyway.

I'm on using Chrome dev mode, Atom as editor tool, and running PHP through MAMP.

Comment: why is the reference assignment being used in $result? using `=` instead of `=&` should work no?

Answer (score 0):

```html
$select_query = " SELECT SEQ FROM TB_VISITOR WHERE VISITOR_NAME = '$visitor_name' AND VISITOR_PHONE_NO = '$visitor_phone_no' ";

$result = $db->query($select_query);

if (mysql_errno()) 
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
else
{
     if( $result->fetchInto($row) )
     {
          $visitor_seq = $row[0];
     }
}
```